# Are game add ons disabled upon xbox live gold membership expiration?

Tags: fallout-4, xbox-one, xbox-network, fallout-4-automatron

I bougth 2 Fallout 4 addons to play in my Xbox One console when I had Xbox live gold membership and about 1 week after the membership expiration, I cannot play them anymore. On the game's start screen they seem to be disabled and the game states that they are not installed. I checked the game hub they are listed there and also checked the store and they were already purchased.
Why I cannot play my game with the addons ?

Comment: Do you have another Xbox One with the DLCs installed on it?

Comment: No, i have only one Xbox One. Perhaps, its just a bug.

Comment: If you have any other games with DLCs, try those. If they work for that game, then perhaps you are right.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. You don't need Gold to buy things. I assume you're still logged in as a Silver account, and that it's the same account with which you originally bought the DLCs?

Comment: @DCShannon Yes, I was logged with the same account that was used to buy DLCs.
It turns out it was just a bug ! I am  able to play my game with dlcs now. 
After one or two days without trying to play i tryed and it worked.
Thank you guys !

Answer (score 2):

Answer was in the comments.

This was a glitch with their Xbox console. There are no restrictions on your ability to play single-player DLC when your Xbox Live Gold subscription expires. Your Silver-level subscription does not prohibit you from purchasing or playing games.

> That doesn't seem right. You don't need Gold to buy things. I assume you're still logged in as a Silver account, and that it's the same account with which you originally bought the DLCs? – DCShannon Nov 15 '16 at 20:52
>
> @DCShannon Yes, I was logged with the same account that was used to buy DLCs. It turns out it was just a bug ! I am able to play my game with dlcs now. After one or two days without trying to play i tryed and it worked. Thank you guys !